# Ubuntu swap not mounted half of the time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, swap

I have about 8 different ubuntu systems using different versions of ubuntu/lubuntu/kubuntu/mythbuntu/etc. Some are physical machines, some are virtual. The issue I always have is that upon booting up, it's a 50/50 chance that the swap partition will be mounted.

Some systems use encrypted home directories, some do not. This issue happens on all my systems. I usually have more than enough ram so it's not a major issue, but it would be nice if the swap was to load each time like it should.

This happens on even my fresh 14.04 installs. It even happened on the first boot of my latest install.

Why does this happen so often with ubuntu and how can we fix this? Surely I am not the only one with this issue.

Comment: If they are all on the same physical machine, are you using the same swap partition for all the \*buntus? If so I would try using a file instead of a partition for swapping, especially on the VMs.

Comment: No, none share a swap. I am not so sure that's a good idea to have multiple running systems share a swap partition. All the systems use the ubuntu default swap setup.

Comment: This is the line I see in /etc/fstab --- /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0 --- basically all my systems are the same here

Comment: No, not a good idea, but I thought I'd check. I've used a mixture of swap partitions and files over the years and never seen this problem. Is it always the same installations that fail to mount the swap? Does `sudo swapon -a` work after reboot? I don't suppose there's a `noauto` entry in **/etc/fstab**, is there?

Comment: ok, my main system which is lubuntu 14.04 and was just setup a few days ago has no swap currently. So I just ran sudo swapon -a and it returned: swapon: /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: stat failed: No such file or directory

Comment: Also, none of the systems have a noauto entry in fstab

Comment: Sorry, my edit got out of sync with your reply. I seems as though your swap drive is not ready when the system tries to mount it. There is information and a proposed solution at http://askubuntu.com/questions/289858/disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap-1-is-not-ready

Comment: as far as which installations, all of them are 50/50. So if I reboot my main system, it'll be 50/50 whether swap mounts. All of the systems have this same issue. I never know if swap mounted till I run "top"

Comment: This seems to be a common problem with this setup: http://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try some of those to see if I can get it working.

Comment: Also http://askubuntu.com/questions/341979/what-to-do-about-the-disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap1-is-not-ready-yet-or - my original suggestion of a swap file would seem to avoid the problem. It works very well, but it is difficult to configure hibernation, not a problem with VMs.